# The power/limit of Teshuva

Tags: sin, repentance-teshuvah

Can I repent (sincerely) after performing ANY active sin and avoid its punishment? Would this be different at a time when there was a religious court which might still apply certain punishments/sacrifices to go along with the repentance? [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/if-you-dont-repent-of-a-sin-will-the-consequence-last-forever/68074#68074) question talks about the consequences without repentance, even if the other stuff is done, but I am curious about the power of the repentance, itself.

So if I kill someone in this day and age, and then do sincere repentance (not that I was planning to "[sin and repent](http://www.frumtoronto.com/Blogger.asp?BlogCategoryID=96&ShowEntryID=6026)" but that I really changed after the act), would there be any other consequence to the murder? Is there a "second chance" afforded by sincere repentance for EVERY sin?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40475/8775.

Answer (score 2):

If I summarize your questions to "does Teshuva always erase all traces of a sin?", the answer seems to be "no, according to the Mishna in Chagiga and Rashi." Here are 3 cases:

1. **A missed Mitzva**

   The Mishna in Chagiga ([9a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2)) mentions sins that leave a trace. Based on the verse in Koheleth ([1:15](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00792.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)) that says  מְעֻוָּת לֹא יוּכַל לִתְקֹן וְחֶסְרוֹן לֹא יוּכַל לְהִמָּנוֹת - something deformed that cannot be fixed, and something missing that cannot be replaced.

   The Mishna brings this with regards to somebody who didn't bring that Chagiga sacrifice during the Chag; once the Chag is over, he can no longer make amends; he has lost the opportunity to do the Mitzva.

   While this isn't an active sin, it's a missed Mitzva. **The Mishna seems to imply there is no way to make amends for a missed Mitzva.**
2. **Leaving behind physical evidence**

   R' Shimon ben Menasya says that the verse refers to having illicit relationships from which a Mamzer is born. For if it referred to theft, that can be returned.

   Rashi explains that since there are facts on the ground, his sin cannot be deleted with Teshuva.

   > **והוליד ממזר.** שהביא פסולין בישראל ויהא זכרון לפיכך אין עונותיו נמחקין בתשובה‏

   Rashi seems to say that Teshuva cannot change reality - **as long as there's a physical trace of the sin, Teshuva cannot be complete.**
3. **Permanent damage**

   The Gemara ([9b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html#HtmpReportNum0015_L2)) is surprised that R' Shimon ben Menasya only mentions when a Mamzer is born - for even if a Mamzer isn't born, there's irreparable damage, for example, if he had an affair with a married lady who becomes forbidden to remain married.

   As Rashi there says: He has no more Teshuva because he did something that cannot be healed. (As opposed to sins like theft for which one can make monetary reparations.)

   > **נטרד מן העולם**. אין לו עוד תשובה לפי שעשה דבר שאין לו רפואה

   Rashi seems to say that **Teshuva can't change reality, and therefore cannot be effective if the sin cannot be remedied**, like causing a divorce. Assumedly this would apply to murder also.

IIRC, there are more cases, like missing a Tefila, that are considered something missing that cannot be replaced. And the Mishna seems to bring Rashbi who may be presenting another case: a Talmid Chacham who abandons his learning.

Here's the relevant snippets of the Gemara:

Chagiga 9a

> **מתני'** מי שלא חג ביו''ט הראשון של חג חוגג את כל הרגל ויו''ט האחרון של חג עבר הרגל ולא חג אינו חייב באחריותו על זה נאמר {קהלת א-טו} מעוות לא יוכל לתקון וחסרון לא יוכל להמנות 
> ‏**ר' שמעון בן מנסייא** אומר איזהו מעוות שאינו יכול להתקן זה הבא על הערוה והוליד ממנה ממזר א''ת בגונב וגוזל יכול הוא להחזירו ויתקן 
> ‏**ר''ש בן יוחי** אומר אין קורין מעוות אלא למי שהיה מתוקן בתחילה ונתעוות ואיזה זה תלמיד חכם הפורש מן התורה:‏

Rashi:

> **מתני' מי שלא חג**. שלא הביא חגיגתו ביום הראשון של חג: ויו''ט האחרון של חג. חוגג שמיני עצרת ואע''ג דרגל בפני עצמו הוא הוי תשלומין לראשון: **והוליד ממזר**. שהביא פסולין בישראל ויהא זכרון לפיכך אין עונותיו נמחקין בתשובה: **יכול להחזיר**. דמי גניבתו וגזלתו לבעלים: **ויתקן**. ויהא מתוקן מן החטא: **מעוות**. מקולקל:‏

Tosafoth: (I'm not sure he agrees)

> **זה הבא על הערוה**. דטפי בושתו ניכר שהממזר נראה לעולם אבל שאר עבירות רוצח וגזלן אין עדיו לפניו. דטפי בושתו ניכר שהממזר נראה לעולם אבל שאר עבירות רוצח וגזלן אין עדיו לפניו‏

Gemara 9b

> ר' שמעון בן מנסיא אומר אי זה הוא מעוות לא יוכל לתקון זה הבא על הערוה והוליד ממנה ממזר וכו': הוליד אין לא הוליד לא והא תניא רבי שמעון בן מנסיא אומר גונב אדם אפשר שיחזיר גנבו ויתקן גוזל אדם אפשר שיחזיר גזלו ויתקן אבל הבא על אשת איש ואסרה לבעלה נטרד מן העולם והלך לו

Rashi

> **:נטרד מן העולם**. אין לו עוד תשובה לפי שעשה דבר שאין לו רפואה
>   
>   **באשת איש**. בלא הוליד נמי יש זכרון לעונו שאסרה על בעלה לא שנא אחותו ולא שנא נכרית: ‏

Answer (score 2):

Maimonides pretty much devotes his [entire first chapter of the Laws of Repentance](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911888/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-One.htm) to your question (particularly law 4).  Basically, the short answer is: no. In fact, according to Maimonides, *teshuva* alone only atones for violations of most positive commandments, not biblical prohibitions. When the Temple and/or Sanhedrin are around, *teshuva* acts as a necessary co-requisite with biblically mandated offerings or punishments.  Without the Temple and Sanhedrin, Yom Kippur, suffering, and/or death are necessary to atone for violations of most commandments.

> **ד**
>   אע"פ שהתשובה מכפרת על הכל ועצמו של יוה"כ מכפר יש עבירות שהן מתכפרים לשעתן ויש עבירות שאין מתכפרים אלא לאחר זמן כיצד עבר אדם על מצות עשה שאין בה כרת ועשה תשובה אינו זז משם עד שמוחלין לו ובאלו נאמר שובו בנים שובבים ארפא משובותיכם וגו' עבר על מצות לא תעשה שאין בה כרת ולא מיתת בית דין ועשה תשובה תשובה תולה ויום הכפורים מכפר ובאלו נאמר כי ביום הזה יכפר עליכם עבר על כריתות ומיתות בית דין ועשה תשובה תשובה ויוה"כ תולין ויסורין הבאין עליו גומרין לו הכפרה ולעולם אין מתכפר לו כפרה גמורה עד שיבואו עליו יסורין ובאלו נאמר ופקדתי בשבט פשעם ובנגעים עונם במה דברים אמורים בשלא חילל את השם בשעה שעבר אבל המחלל את השם אע"פ שעשה תשובה והגיע יום הכפורים והוא עומד בתשובתו ובאו עליו יסורין אינו מתכפר לו כפרה גמורה עד שימות אלא תשובה יוה"כ ויסורין שלשתן תולין ומיתה מכפרת שנאמר ונגלה באזני ה' צבאות וגו' אם יכופר העון הזה לכם עד תמותון:
>
> **4** Even though Teshuvah atones for all [sins] and the essence of Yom
>   Kippur brings atonement, [there are different levels of sin and hence,
>   differences in the degree of atonement.] There are sins that can be
>   atoned for immediately and other sins which can only be atoned for
>   over the course of time. What is implied?
>
> If a person violates a positive command which is not punishable by
>   karet and repents, he will not leave that place before he is forgiven.
>   Concerning these sins, [Jeremiah 3:22] states: "Return, faithless
>   children! I will heal your rebellious acts."
>
> If a person violates a prohibition that is not punishable by karet or
>   execution by the court and repents, Teshuvah has a tentative effect
>   and Yom Kippur brings atonement as [Leviticus, loc. cit. states "This
>   day will atone for you."
>
> If a person violates [sins punishable by] karet or execution by the
>   court and repents, Teshuvah and Yom Kippur have a tentative effect and
>   the sufferings which come upon him complete the atonement. He will
>   never achieve complete atonement until he endures suffering for
>   concerning these [sins, Psalms 89:33] states: "I will punish their
>   transgression with a rod."
>
> When does the above apply: When the desecration of God's name is not
>   involved in the transgression. However, a person who desecrated God's
>   name, even though he repented, Yom Kippur arrived while he continued
>   his repentance, and he experienced suffering, will not be granted
>   complete atonement until he dies. The three: repentance, Yom Kippur,
>   and suffering have a tentative effect and death atones as [Isaiah
>   22:14] states: "It was revealed in my ears [by] the Lord of Hosts,
>   surely this iniquity will not be atoned for until you die."